# Overflow causes global scrollbar to appear even with parent element `overflow: auto`

Tags: html, css

I want to have two containers(green and red in the example) to be sized 100% of available space(in the example all space except header). Second column have large content which overflows vertically. I would like only second column to have scrollbar without body scrollbar. If I remove header everything works as intended but with header I see global scrollbar. Why?

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div>Header</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div style="height: 4000px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

Problem imho is that the column is overflowing the container as well which defaults to
 `overflow: visible`

I set the overflow of container to hidden
Then I set the header to 25px fixed (which is optional)
Left column should now take 100% of container height correctly.
Right column should overflow: scroll within parent container.

If you know right column will overflow vertically you might as well use:
`overflow-y: scroll;`

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
#header {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div style="height: 4000px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Behaviour of `overflow: auto` depends on the browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Running your example have exactly same problem. I see two scrollbars, I want only one on the second red container, there should not be scrollbar on the body

Comment: Actually I just noticed that your code is working on my browser already, what browser are you testing with. Your code (and mine) works fine for me (1 Scroll bar on the red div) in chrome and safari on macos. Or did i misunderstand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just checked in Chrome/Firefox on Mac neither mine or yours versions work correctly. I see two scrollbars.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: do you have an explanation for `overflow: hidden` for container class? Seems so random, why there is overflow there?

Comment: I think the overflowing right column is overflowing it's container, which is defaulting to `overflow: visible`But maybe someone else knows more about this